# checking for null values in configuration file

Tags: c#, .net

Which way is better to check whether a config value is null?

```
if(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["configValue"]!=null)
{
  var _queue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["configValue"]
}
```

or this way?

```
var _queue=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["configValue"] ?? null;
```

Comment: How about just `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["configValue"]` ?

Comment: Why don't you run the code and find out for yourself.

Comment: Both ways are just the same, semantically speaking. The question is whether you want your var to be assigned when there is no config value or not. In both cases, there is a need for a null check.

Comment: The second way is generally used if you intend to assign a default value if the config is null. ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["configValue"] ?? defaultValue;

Comment: in the second one, wouldn't  _queue be set to null if ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["configValue"] equals null in his example.

Comment: The answer would depend on what you want to do when the value is null. Please make that clear in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use these extensions. This is abbreviated. There are a few other methods for parsing values to other types.

This way I can be explicit with the error messages so that if a setting is required but missing it doesn't fail silently or throw a vague exception.

```
public static class AppSettingsExtensions
{
    public static string Required(this NameValueCollection appSettings, string key)
    {
        var settingsValue = appSettings[key];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(settingsValue))
            throw new MissingAppSettingException(key);
        return settingsValue;
    }

    public static string ValueOrDefault(this NameValueCollection appSettings, string key, string defaultValue)
    {
        return appSettings[key] ?? defaultValue;
    }
}

public class MissingAppSettingException : Exception
{
    internal MissingAppSettingException(string key, Type expectedType)
        : base(string.Format(@"An expected appSettings value with key ""{0}"" and type {1} is missing.", key, expectedType.FullName))
    { }
    public MissingAppSettingException(string key)
        : base(string.Format(@"An expected appSettings value with key ""{0}"" is missing.", key))
    { }
}
```

Usage:

```
    var setting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Required("thisCantBeMissing");
    var optionalSetting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.ValueOrDefault("thisCanBeMissing", "default value");
```

The second one is handy because I often never need to create the appSettings key. I can just use the default.

Answer (score 1):

something along these lines

```
string val = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["configValue"];
if (val == null)
    Console.WriteLine("Missing appSettings configuration 'configValue'");
else if (val == string.Empty)
    Console.WriteLine("appSettings configuration 'configValue' not set");
else
    Console.WriteLine("appSettings configuration 'configValue' is " + val);
```

But usually, even if someone has not set value, you want your application to still function...

```
string val = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["configValue"];
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val))
    val = "default value";
```

Comment: thanks! what would be the most terse way of expressing your second block of code?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' I would guess, if you want a one-liner: `string val = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["configValue"]) ? "Default Value" : ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["configValue"];`